# Splitting the string in key=value groups using Regex (Java)

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I am not big expert in regexp, that's why i ask you to suggest an efficient way of splitting this string in the key=value groups.

The input string:

```
x-x="11111" y-y="John-Doe 23" db {rty='Y453'} code {codeDate='2000-03-01T00:00:00'}
```

What i need is to get key=value pairs:

```
key=x-x, value="11111"
key=y-y, value="John-Doe 23"
key=rty, value='Y453'
key=codeDate, value='2000-03-01T00:00:00'
```

My solution is here but i fear it's not the simplest one.

```
String str = "x-x=\"11111\" y-y=\"John-Doe 23\" db {rty='Y453'} code {codeDate='2000-03-01T00:00:00'}";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+-*\\w*)=((\"|')(\\w+( |-|:)*)+(\"|'))").matcher(str);

while(m.find()) {
    String key = m.group(1);
    String value = m.group(2);
    System.out.printf("key=%s, value=%s\n", key, value);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do the keys always consist of letters/digits, `_` and `-` chars?

Comment: Keys have fixed names: 'x-x', 'y-y', 'rty' and 'codeDate'. But in value can be pretty anything..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex with 3 capturing groups and a back-reference:

```
([\w-]+)=((['"]).*?\3)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZ2riG/1)

```
RegEx Breakup:
```

- `([\w-]+)`: Match and capture key name in group #1
- `=`: Match `=`
- `(`: Start group #2

  - `(['"])`: Match and capture a quote in group #3
  - `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any character (lazy match)
  - `\3`: Back-reference to group #3 to match closing quote of same type
- `)`: End of capture group #2

You will get your matches in `.group(1)` and `.group(2)`.

Comment: Aren't there actually three capturing groups in the regex?

Comment: Yes there are three :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i realized my mistakes and over-complexity of solution. :) Actually as alternative this solution can used ([\w-]+)=((['"]).*?(['"]))

Comment: That can be used but it will also match `'abc"` (one single and one double quote)

Answer (score 0):

For select values in between single and double quotes value in group 1

```
String ResultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[\"'](.*?[^\\\\])[\"']", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```